# Error in plot.new() : internal read error in PDF_endpage

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix of my data.

Here's my code:

```
data <- read.table("path/to/data", header=T, sep='\t')
cor <- cor(data)
corrplot(cor, method="color", type="upper")
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Error in plot.new() : internal read error in PDF_endpage
```

I've never seen this error before and there isn't much on google. Any help?

Comment: are you writing your figures to PDF using `pdf()` or have you set new values to the graphing parameters using `par`, maybe `par(mfrow=c(i, j))`? If so, then please include the surrounding code.

Comment: @Imo I have nothing else. This is my code. the file is produced by another script and I'm just using `cor` to reallocate the columns for the correlation matrix

Comment: Have you tried the code with a fresh session?

Comment: @Imo yes. No luck

Comment: @Imo just for fun, I logged in to a local server and run the code. it ran perfectly. So, I'm guessing it was a MAC OS X issue...

Comment: Huh, maybe something to do with how graphics are produced in that OS for the version of R you have installed. Interesting.

Comment: @Imo it's amazing that I got 9 hits on Google when I looked it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error just after cleaning up some temp files and solved it by updating my packages:

```
update.packages()
```

To me it happened after I removed some temp R files. Not sure why does `pdf()` files live in temp folders, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and was finally able to resolve it by using `graphics.off()`. I had to run the command twice but then plotting worked again.